# Tools for running and monitoring jobs in cluster

Tags: monitoring, cluster-computing, pbs

We got these two clusters with eight nodes each, and we are looking for a good cluster framework that would allow us to launch jobs, has an inbuilt scheduler with different scheduling policies and a monitoring system with web frontend. Each of the nodes are running on Ubuntu 11.04. Both commercial and opensource are OK.

Some of them i saw were, 
TORQUE and MAUI.(Not sure if it has a web frontend for monitoring)
SLURM and MAUI.
GEXEC and GANGLIA.(Doesn't have a scheduler)

Which product(s) would you recommend? Also is there any advantage using cluster operating systems like MOSIX instead of tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paid version of Maui is called Moab (it normally uses TORQUE as the RM). It also can be sold with monitoring tools as well. I think Moab is a really good product, but I am strongly biased towards it (I work for the company that develops TORQUE/Moab).